# Typedef map as return type to a function throws a compiler error

Tags: c++, maps, containers, typedef

Typedef a `map` and using the `typedef` name as a return parameter to a function fails.

Below is a pseudo code explaining the scenario:

```
/**
* a.h
*/
class A 
{
   public:
       typedef std::map<string,int> Int_map;
       A();
       ~A();

       const Int_map& getMap(); 

   private:
     Int_map my_map;

}


/**
* a.cpp
*/

 A::A() {}

 A::~A() {}


 const Int_map& A::getMap() // gives a compiler error : Int_map does not name a type
{
   return my_map;
}
```

However if I use  the following declaration in "a.cpp", there is no compiler error. (Note:  a.h file still contains the declaration as const `Int_map& A::getMap()`)

```
  const std::map<string,int>& A::getMap()
```

What causes this behaviour?

Analogous to the same behaviour, I have another question related to `std::string` :

I understand that string is also a typedef in C++ and a template is used.
How does the functions returning `string` work in C++ and `typedef map` throws an error?

Comment: Int_map -> A::Int_map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scoping. When you define the function you are not in the scope of the class `A` but in the global scope. You need to use `A::Int_map`.

It's the same reason you need to use the scoping operator in `A::getMap`.